# Error Loading extension section v3_ca [centos7]

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, openssl, centos, logstash

so I am trying to install elasticsearch on my OpenVZ VPS and as I was following the guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-centos-7)

While generating the SSL certificate, I tried both options but I'm hitting a wall now. I looked through internet and it didn't help me.

The Command I used

```
openssl req -config /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf -x509 -days 3650 -batch -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private/logstash-forwarder.key -out certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
```

Result I got

```
Error Loading extension section v3_ca
140327857534880:error:22097082:X509 V3 routines:DO_EXT_NCONF:unknown extension name:v3_conf.c:124:
140327857534880:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:v3_conf.c:93:name=SubjectAltName, value=IP: xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

One Point to note is that I added

```
subjectAltName = IP: xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

As I followed the guide linked above.

---

Any help is appreciated

Regards,

inlifethrill

Answer (score 1):

Just considering that you're about to create a local installation and that you want to test elasticsearch/logstash.

You probably miss section `[v3_ca]` in the `openssl.cnf` file.

Here is what i've tried (on a CentOS 7 host:)

```
$ mkdir /var/tmp/test
$ cd /var/tmp/test
$ mkdir private
$ mkdir certs
$ openssl req -config /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf -x509 -days 3650 \
    -batch -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private/logstash-forwarder.key \
    -out certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.....+++
........+++
writing new private key to 'private/logstash-forwarder.key'

$ ll -Rt certs private
certs:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 johnny johnny 1220 Mar 22 11:49 logstash-forwarder.crt

private:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 johnny johnny 1704 Mar 22 11:49 logstash-forwarder.key
```

The `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf` has the following section: (stripped commented out lines)

```
[ v3_ca ]
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints = CA:true
```

I'm using default settings from the file provided by `openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Note that you probably want to create those files in directory `/etc/pki/tls`